# Serialization/Deserialization with ISerializable

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, iserializable

Good morning,
I am working on a C# application and I need to serialize an object with ISerializable interface but
I do not how to do it. My object has no properties, it just have some methods. See below the code :

```
public interface ILogger  
{  
  void logErrorMessage(string errorMessage);  
  void logInfoMessage(string infoMessage);  
  void logWarningMessage(string warningMessage);  
}  



[Serializable]  
class MessageLogger: ILogger, ISerializable  
{  
  
  public MessageLogger()  
  { }  
  
  public void logErrorMessage(string errorMessage)  
  {  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR :" + errorMessage);  
  }  
  
  public void logInfoMessage(string infoMessage)  
  {  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:" + infoMessage);  
  }  
  
  public void logWarningMessage(string warningMessage)  
  {  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WARNING:" + warningMessage);  
  }  
  
  public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)  
  {  
  }  
}
```

My question is what I have to put in GetObjectData ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Romain.

Comment: for me it makes no sense to serialize a logger, as you noticed it has no meaningful state/properties. for example it would serialize to `{}` as JSON, wich is completely useless

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this, it explains it pretty clearly:
[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Please edit the answer to contain relevant info, see [why link-only answers are bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/299295).